# Unable to assign QList<QUrl> to QString

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop, qml, qtquick2

I'm encountering this error:

```
Unable to assign QList<QUrl> to QString
```

when trying to **directly assign** the result of `drop.urls` (obtained from `DropArea`'s `onDropped` handler) to a Label's `text` property in Python.

Based on [this doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-url.html), I tried `Qt.resolvedUrl` (to convert the type to a string) as shown in the following code. However, it results in an empty text label. The urls I'm working with start with "**file:///**".

What am I doing wrong?

```
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.14

Window {
    id: root
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: "Drop Test"
    property var attachments: "empty"

    DropArea {
        id: dropArea;
        anchors.fill: parent
        onEntered: {
            root.color = "gray";
            console.log("You entered drop area")
            drag.accept (Qt.LinkAction);
        }
        onDropped: {
            console.log("You dropped " + drop.urls)
            attachments = Qt.resolvedUrl(drop.urls)
        }
    }

    Label {
        id: mLableId
        text: attachments
    }
}
```

Assigning a URL to a string seems like such an obvious question, but if it has already been asked in the context of Python and Qt Quick, I have not find any such existing questions after searching since yesterday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

urls is a list of url so you will have to iterate and concatenate:

```
onDropped: {
    console.log("You dropped " + drop.urls)
    var str = ""
    for(var i in drop.urls){
        var url = drop.urls[i]
        str += Qt.resolvedUrl(url)
    }
    attachments = str
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Where exactly can I find documentation on the type `urls`? I'm sure it's out there (probably many places), but I did not see it. The only thing I found yesterday or today was for `url` (non array) here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-url.html. (I'm probably stupidly overlooking some obvious documentation.)

Comment: @MountainX-for-Monica Do you mean documentation about the "urls" property of the "drop" element or do you mean the type of data "url"?

Comment: In the code above, the for-loop is only executed once. The first log statement will show multiple comma separated items, but a log inside the loop is only ever executed one. I guess the for-loop needs to recognize a comma separated list as a list of multiple items, or the conversion of drop.urls into a string array would need to be done before the loop. What do you suggest?

Comment: @MountainX-for-Monica mmm, you are assuming many things. The for-loop does not recognize commas since that is not their task. Bye

Comment: My point was that (as far as I can tell) the code is not working. The for-loop only executes once, even when multiple items are contained in drop.urls.

Comment: @MountainX-for-Monica what is the output of `console.log("You dropped " + drop.urls)`?

Comment: Sorry, your code works fine! My error is elsewhere. If I can't fix it, I'll ask a new question.